# How to groupby, iterate over rows and count in pandas?

Tags: pandas, loops, group-by, count, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with columns `city`, `date`, `source` and `count` of each source.
I need to group by `city`, then iterate over rows of `date` column with the following condition: check each row and if the difference between them is <30 days then find start_date(min) and end_date(max)  for the group of dates that meet condition, and add them as a separate columns. Also, count the source type and add again as separate columns.

```
    city        date        source  count
0   Alexandria  2022-10-13  black   117
1   Alexandria  2022-10-14  black   85
2   Alexandria  2022-10-15  black   63
3   Alexandria  2022-10-16  black   190
4   Alexandria  2022-10-17  black   389
5   Alexandria  2022-10-18  black   284
6   Alexandria  2022-10-19  black   179
7   Amsterdam   2018-08-05  red     1
8   Amsterdam   2018-08-28  red     111
9   Amsterdam   2019-08-17  red     1669
10  Amsterdam   2019-08-18  red     1584
11  Amsterdam   2019-08-19  red     940
12  Amsterdam   2019-08-21  red     1498
13  Amsterdam   2019-08-22  red     2281
14  Amsterdam   2019-08-23  red     2038
15  Amsterdam   2019-08-24  red     1516
16  Amsterdam   2019-08-25  red     1952
17  Amsterdam   2019-08-26  red     1434
18  Amsterdam   2019-08-27  red     881
19  Amsterdam   2019-08-29  red     1482
20  Amsterdam   2019-08-30  red     978
21  Amsterdam   2019-08-31  red     1423
22  Amsterdam   2019-09-01  red     1120
23  Amsterdam   2019-09-02  red     1117
24  Amsterdam   2019-09-06  red     1
```

To reproduce my dataframe:

```
# initialize list of lists
data1 = [['Alexandria', '2022-10-13', 'black', 117],
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-14', 'black', 85], 
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-15', 'black', 63],
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-16', 'black', 190],
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-17', 'black', 389],
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-18', 'black', 284],
     ['Alexandria', '2022-10-19', 'black', 179],
     ['Amsterdam', '2018-08-05', 'red', 1],
     ['Amsterdam', '2018-08-28', 'red', 111],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-17', 'red', 1669],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-18', 'red', 1584],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-19', 'red', 940],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-21', 'red', 1498],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-22', 'red', 2281],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-23', 'red', 2038],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-24', 'red',1516],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-25', 'red', 1952],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-26', 'red', 1434],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-27', 'red', 881],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-29', 'red', 1482],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-30', 'red', 978],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-31', 'red', 1423],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-09-01', 'red', 1120],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-09-02', 'red',1117],
     ['Amsterdam', '2019-09-06', 'red', 1],
    ]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['city', 'date', 'source','count'])
```

The output needed(looks like pivot table):
So, for Alexandria i have only 1 round where dates are less than 30 days between them: from 2022-10-13 till 2022-10-19 (6th row). These 2 dates are min and max.
For Amsterdam we have 2 rounds of dates that have less that 30 days between them: 1st round are rows 7-8, 2nd round are rows 9-24.
Between 8 and 9 rows for Amsterdam there are more than 30 days, meaning it starts a new round.

```
    city        start_date  end_date    black   red
0   Alexandria  2022-10-13  2022-10-19  1307    0
1   Amsterdam   2018-08-05  2018-08-28  0      112
2   Amsterdam   2019-08-17  2019-09-06  0      21914
```

To reproduce the output:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['Alexandria', '2022-10-13', '2022-10-19', 1307, 0], 
    ['Amsterdam', '2018-08-05', '2018-08-28', 0, 112],
    ['Amsterdam', '2019-08-17', '2019-09-06', 0,21914 ]]


# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['city', 'start_date', 'end_date','black', 'red'])
```

Comment: Do not put link to images. I think you may be able to copy the output (I, as many programmers, will not open random links from random people).

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not fully answer the question, but is hopefully helpful in getting you partly there, since you did not show what you have tried (if anything). The 30 days part presumably would involve some custom way of grouping and aggregating the data which I have not attempted here. As such, this answer shows how to:

- Create `start_date` and `end_date` columns for minimum and maximum dates grouped by city, respectively
- Sum the `count` for each `source` value into new columns for each identified `source` value (`black` and `red`)
- Merge the two resultant dataframes into a single one

This answer assumes the original data is in a dateframe named `df`.

### Minimum and maximum dates

I know this is not exactly what is wanted due to the 30 days logic, but shows a straightforward grouping by city with minimum and maximum dates for each.

```
date_agg_df = df.groupby("city").agg({"date": ["min", "max"]}).reset_index()
date_agg_df.columns = ["city", "start_date", "end_date"]
```

Data in `date_agg_df`:

```
         city  start_date    end_date
0  Alexandria  2022-10-13  2022-10-19
1   Amsterdam  2018-08-05  2019-09-06
```

### Sum the count of each source value

```
black_red_df = df.fillna(0).pivot_table(index="city", columns="source", values="count", aggfunc="sum").fillna(0).reset_index()
black_red_df.columns = ["city", "black", "red"]
```

Data in `black_red_df`:

```
         city   black      red
0  Alexandria  1307.0      0.0
1   Amsterdam     0.0  22026.0
```

### Merge the dataframes

```
mrg_df = pd.merge(date_agg_df, black_red_df, on="city")
```

Data in `mrg_df`:

```
         city  start_date    end_date   black      red
0  Alexandria  2022-10-13  2022-10-19  1307.0      0.0
1   Amsterdam  2018-08-05  2019-09-06     0.0  22026.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is helpful.
In terms of less than 30 days, i transformed the column to datetime() and calculated the diff() between dates, i got 0 and 1 (bool) for <30 and now i am at the stage where i need rows that respect the sequence 01010101... one after each other, and all the rest are removed.That would be all the rounds for each city-the start(each 0 zero) and end dates(the last 1 before next 0)). So, i focus on this, in R there is a solution for this on stack, in Python there is regex, but i need to adapt so that the sequence to check is row after row.

Comment: Consider upvoting my answer if helpful (but don't accept it since it doesn't fully solve this). One possible strategy is to sort by date then add two new columns, one for earliest/min date in "sequence", one for a date group identifier. Compare each date for same city in sequence to min date for that sequence, and if delta exceeds 30, increment group identifier. Then you use above steps and group by the city and that sequence/group ID.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I tried to upvote your answer right away, but i can't- it's says i need 15 reputation to cast a vote.. Since this is my first time posting on stack .